# Is it possible to run command on different thread inside other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, arcore, ui-thread

So I want to check if nodes are in certain range and if so, draw them or not. 
The nodes are checked inside a timer, so a thread is created. Only issue right now is that method setRenderable() have to be called from UI thread. So is there a way to bypass that ? I need this to update in certain interval that's why I create timer.

```
 public void updateNodes()
    {
        Camera camera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            int last = 0;
            int copy_last = 0;
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Vector3 camera_position = camera.getWorldPosition();
                // We're checking all nodes for distance between them
                for(Node al : copied_nodes_list){
                    if(last<copy_last) last++;
                    else if(countDistanceOfNodes(al,camera_position)<3.0 && copy_last >= last) {
                        al.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
                        last++;
                        copy_last = last;
                    }
                    else {
                            al.setRenderable(andyRenderable);   
                    }
                }
                last = 0;

            }
        },0,250);
    }
```

Comment: Does the GUI framework not have its own "Timer" class that "fires" timed events on the GUI thread? (E.g., the Swing framework has `javax.swing.Timer`)

Comment: I'm using ARCore from google, I can't find any method which would behave like timer. 
This is the documentation. https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/Scene.OnUpdateListener

Comment: @SolomonSlow I fount that there's an android method called runOnUiThread(). Do you think this might solve the case? The only problem is that I have to pass an runnable, not timer.

Comment: Almost as good:  It means you'll need two `Runnables`; Let the first one be called by the timer, and then have it submit the second one to `runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a variable in your class.
- Set the value when the object is initialized or write a setter against that variable.
- Within the run function, check against the condition against that variable and write the business rules accordingly.

Comment: I don't quite get it. How this will help me with using setRenderable()?  Could You explain little more?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, most GUI frameworks are "single threaded," meaning that only one distinguished thread (known as the, "GUI thread", "event thread", "main thread", etc.) is allowed to call any of the framework methods. Other threads typically are not allowed to call any GUI function except maybe, to post an event to a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there's function in android called runOnUiThread(); Which basically doing whats it's called. I attach the working code.

```
public void updateNodes()
    {
        Camera camera = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().getCamera();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            int last = 0;
            int copy_last = 0;
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Vector3 camera_position = camera.getWorldPosition();

                // We're checking all nodes for distance between them
                for(Node al : copied_nodes_list){
                    camera_position = camera.getWorldPosition();

                    if(last<copy_last) last++;

                    else if(countDistanceOfNodes(al,camera_position)<3.0 && copy_last >= last) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                al.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
                            }
                        });
                        last++;
                        copy_last = last;
                    }
                    else {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                @Override
                                public void run(){
                                    al.setRenderable(null);
                                }
                            });

                    }
                }
                last = 0;
            }
        },0,100);

    }
```